# UIPageViewController accessibility or voiceover

Tags: accessibility, uipageviewcontroller, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I'm using UIPageViewController to swipe through pages (UIViewController array). I push the page view controller on the top navigation controller.

While I start the app, I could page through all the VCs inside the page view controller. However,the "three finger swipe" on page view controller doesn't work. It just doesn't get the scroll events.

Any insight on what's going wrong here?

Comment: Did you implement `accessibilityScroll:`?

Comment: Did you get anysolution for the same?

Comment: Double tapping screen allows to move to the next view controller.

Comment: @GoodSp33d for accessibility wasn't it you have to swipe with 3 fingers for scrolling?

Comment: I'm also having same issue, @Swapnil Patel did you find any solution?

Comment: I had similar problem and realised you have to tap on an element somewhere within the scrolling content and then swipe with 3 fingers. I think this is because when the page loads the accessibility is focused on the nav bar or top of the page.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried setting the value for `view.isAccessibilityElement` on the UIViewControllers in your pageViewControllers' array?

*(on viewController.m/viewController.swift file)*
`self.view.isAccessibilityElement = true`

The code above should work in both Objective-C and Swift (v. 2.2 and higher, maybe lower versions as well)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

In storyboard, change the Transition Style in attribute inspector of the pageViewController to "Scroll" instead of "Page Curl".